# How to pause a stored procedure for a while?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am using Oracle DB Server and I have a stored procedure which will be executed in parallel by different flows. This stored procedure uses one of our tables in the database for inserting and deleting records. At a certain point in the stored procedure, I want it to pause for a while and then execute.

What statement can I write to pause the stored procedure for a while without locking the table it is using?

What are the alternatives available in Oracle stored procedures to achieve this kind of functionality?

Can I use `DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(seconds)`? As I said the same table is used in parallel by different flows, will this `DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(n)` procedure lock the table while the stored procedure is pausing? And will it consume CPU cycles when the stored procedure is in sleep state?

Are there any other alternatives to achieve this functionality other than using `DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(n)` procedure in Oracle DB Server?

Comment: try [sleep](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep)? Clarify which DB server are you using..

Comment: I am using oracle DB.I don't want the store procedure  consume cpu cycles while it is in pause state ,is it possible with sleep?

Comment: Can you mention then that in your question.. provide all possible information and provide which data server you are using then we could help.

Comment: What is the purpose of the pause?  Is it to synchronize threads?

Comment: `dbms_lock.sleep` will not take out new locks, but it will **not release** locks already held. So if one updates a few hundred rows and then sleeps prior to committing, write locks will be held on those rows for the duration.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(n)` procedure. A procedure that stops the execution of the current thread for `n` seconds.

Note that `DBMS_LOCK` is not granted to PUBLIC (or anybody else) by default.  So you will need to ask your friendly DBA to issue the requisite EXECUTE privilege.

Comment: As i said the same table is used in parallel by different flows,will this DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(n) procedure lock table the stored procedure is using? and will it consume CPU cycles when the stored procedure is in sleep state.?

Comment: The SLEEP procedure do not lock the table. It will consume minimum amount of CPU.

Comment: If DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(seconds) takes only seconds,then How to make the stored procedure sleep for few microseconds?

Comment: 10s of milliseconds is possible. _The smallest increment can be entered in hundredths of a second; for example, 1.95 is a legal time value._ http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lock.htm#ARPLS66782

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as a task for `DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE` package
see documentation here [DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_parallel_ex.htm#ARPLS2)

to stop your processing you can use `STOP_TASK`
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_parallel_ex.htm#ARPLS67379

```
STOP_TASK Procedure
This procedure stops the task and related job slaves.

Syntax

DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.STOP_TASK (
   task_name       IN VARCHAR2);
Parameters
```